# Design pattern: bundle models in controller or in service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

We use asp.net mvc with Entity Framework as our ORM.

Our database is really old and was built long time ago. So foreign keys are missing and we can't add it now. We need to bundle different models into ViewModels. We are not sure if we should do the initial model bundling in difference service methods or in the controller.

So my question is what design pattern and practice you think is best.
Bundle in controller:

```
 public class PlayerController : ApiController
 {
     private readonly IPlayerService _playerService;
     private readonly IItemService _itemService;

     public PlayerController(IPlayerService playerService, IItemService itemService)
     {
         _playerService = playerService;
         _itemService = itemService;
     }


     public UserViewModel Get(int id)
     {
        var user = playerService.GetUser(id);
         var item = itemService.GetItem(id);
         var userViewModel = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel(user);
         userViewModel.item = Mapper.Map<ItemViewModel(item);
         return userViewModel;
     }
 }
```

Or bundle in the service:

```
public class PlayerController : ApiController
 {
     private readonly IPlayerService _playerService;
     private readonly IItemService _itemService;

     public PlayerController(IPlayerService playerService, IItemService itemService)
     {
         _playerService = playerService;
         _itemService = itemService;
     }


     public UserViewModel Get(int id)
     {
        var userWithItem = playerService.GetUserWithItem(id);
        return Mapper.Map<UserViewModel(userWithItem);
     }
 }
```

The call to getting the item would be done in the "GetUserWithItem" instead, like this:

```
public User GetUserWithItem(int id)
{
    var user = _dbContext.user.Find(id);
    user.Item = _dbContext.item.Where(x=>x.userId => id);

    return user;
}
```

Which is the 'correct' way of doing it that would offer most benefits?

Comment: Too many unknowns to know which is 'correct'.  Quick rule of thumb I use...Are you going to need a given view model in more than one controller? If so, I'd lean to doing the heavy lifting in a service layer.  If the view model only is needed in one controller, I'd lean to do the work in the controller.  That being said, I tend to lean to very thin controllers. Don't like to bury code there where it is harder to re-use and test.

Comment: I prefer to keep a controller so thin as much as I can. In this case I would move even `UserViewModel Get(int id)` method away from controller to Service or special UI layer.

Comment: I prefer having one service call per action method, and leaving it up to the service layer (and beyond) to formulate the data into an appropriate model. When I differ, it is only on the model piece when it is something truly UI specific, such as `SelectList` items. In that case, the service will pass down the data (one call), and the controller can do the additional work of translation into the appropriate format relevant to the view.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov Generally speaking I think ViewModel's should not leave controller layer. It's about keeping data that you do not want to communicate with the front-end separate.

Answer (score 1):

Second approach looks good quite neat then the first one. Keep controller as light as possible.

A suggestion, The dependencies should be exposed via **abstraction** not **implementations**. Instead of using concrete classes of `PlayerService` and `ItemService` you should introduce abstraction via Interfaces. Use `IPlayerService` and `IItemService` in constructor injection.

Comment: Thanks for answer. They are interfaces, it's just that I quickly wrote this question. Edited.